# Android Studio can't install app on physical device (but adb can access it)

Tags: android, android-studio

The run commands are disabled

[image]

Also if I use `Alt+Shift+F10` then select the app module, it shows can't find runner error

[image]

I've tried invalidate cache, clean project, rebuild project.
I just can't run apps with android studio, but I can build an apk and then run it on the device with adb.
Also when I create a fresh new project, the same error persists.

Comment: Have you set up an emulator, or connected a device via USB debugging?

Comment: a device with USB debugging

Comment: Open a terminal window or command prompt and execute `adb devices`. What output do you get?

Comment: I get `192.168.43.1:5555      device product:vince model:Redmi_Note_5 device:vince transport_id:1`

Comment: I can build apk and then install it with adb but can't just directly do `Shift+F10`